# How to Stop SetInterval on ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a little gps monitoring, but I have a problem, it can't stop an Interval.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    self.map = self.createMap();
    self.monitoring();

    G.event.addListener(self.map, 'zoom_changed', () => self.handleZoomChange())
    self.intv = setInterval(() => {
        self.monitoring();
    },5e3);
}

componentDidUnMount() {
    G.event.clearListeners(map, 'zoom_changed')
}
```

So how to fix its? Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Nothing in your code makes any attempt to stop the interval. Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "clearInterval(self.intv);"? You also can use some flag and check at every timer iteration if it is needed to complete current iteration. For example:

```
this.__intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (!this.__needIterate) return clearInterval(this.__intervalId);
    this.monitoring();
}.bind(this), this.__interval);
```

Comment: Ya, I've been tried `clearInterval(self.intv)` but still looping

Comment: Are you sure you dont delete timer ID while program is working? Try to use other name of the timer at first. Next try to call "clearInterval()"
 right after creating of the interval. Next you can check ID of the interval when you try to clear it (write "console.log(self.intv);").

To sum up there is some typical error it is needed to recognize. "clearInterval" do their work correctly.

P.S. I see you have big interval. It is possible to use "setTimeout" instead of "setInterval".